# google ai platform model requires more memory than allowed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to build on top of [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-text-classifier-shap) example. I am trying to deploy the shap explainer as a custom prediction routine on google AI platform. Unfortunately when I create the version I get the following error:

```
Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: Model requires more memory than allowed. Please try to decrease the model size and re-deploy. If you continue to have error, please contact Cloud ML.
```

Furthermore, instead of text i am working with images, and the shap explainer is a GradientExplainer.
I have sent a message to google support, but the only result I have achieved is "The Free Trial status of project xxxxx has been upgraded and you are no longer entitled to free technical support. ". Sweet. I have also tried on a no free trial account, and I get the same problem. It is not related to the account being free. It just happened that I have sent the email from my personal account. Any suggestions?

Comment: apparently just `import shap` causes the error. Easy to replicate at least

Comment: What type of instance are you using in Cloud ML Engine?

Comment: How big is your model? Note that legacy systems have Max model size of 500mb, while new ones up to 2Gb. I’m having same problem as my model is 7Gb