# 45 MB model too big for Google AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I'm trying to use AI platform to deploy a scikit-learn pipeline. The size of the model.joblib file I'm tryin to deploy is 45 megabytes.

- python version: 3.7
- framework: scikit-learn(==0.20.4)
- Single Core CPU, Quad Core CPU (Beta)

I've used the following command to deploy as well as GUI

```
 gcloud beta ai-platform versions create v0 \                                                                              
  --model test_watch_model \
  --origin gs://rohan_test_watch_model \
  --runtime-version=1.15 \
  --python-version=3.7 \
  --package-uris=gs://rohan_test_watch_model/train_custom-0.1.tar.gz \
  --framework=scikit-learn \
  --project=xxxx
```

This is the setup.py file I'm using, in case the problem might lie with the libraries.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='train_custom',
    version='0.1',
    scripts=[
        # 'train_custom.py',
        # 'data_silo_custom.py',
        # 'dataset_custom.py',
        # 'preprocessor_custom.py'
        'all.py'
    ],
    install_requires=[
        "torch==1.5.1",
        "transformers==3.0.2",
        "farm==0.4.6"
    ]
)
```

I also tried removing pytorch from setup.py and using torch 1.3 from http://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ai-pytorch/readme.txt but that leaves me with this same error message.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: Model requires more memory than allowed. Please try to decrease the model size and re-deploy. If you continue to experience errors, please contact support.
```

Comment: What command do you use to deploy the model? Have you tried to change the `machineType` parameter?

Comment: Hi Matteo, I've updated the question with the command. I've also tried the GUI. I've tried different machines types in the GUI, tried Singe Core, Quad Core.

Comment: The memory limit in this case should be 2GB of model, so I don't think it's a size issue... Take a look at this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539603/google-ai-platform-model-requires-more-memory-than-allowed), maybe you're importing something similar?

Comment: Let's gather more information: 1) share the output `gsutil ls -l gs://rohan_test_watch_model/train_custom-0.1.tar.gz` to see the model's size 2) share the [stacktrace logs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/troubleshooting#getting_information_from_the_logs), there could be messages that can help, please note that the logs should be enabled with [--enable-logging](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-predict#requesting_logs_for_online_prediction_requests) 3) Please try a different machine type and let us know the results, e.g. mls1-c4-m4.